# Where can I get Extjs 5 "executive dashboard" example source code?

Tags: extjs

I have downloaded an extjs-docs-5.0.0 package. But I cannot find it in the "example" folder.

Where can I get it? An avaliable link is best!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By 'extjs-docs-5.0.0'-package, do you mean the documentation? The source code for this application is in the 'examples/executive-dashboard' of the actual ExtJS 5.0 package, not the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Code can be downloaded from here

https://github.com/bjornharrtell/extjs

Comment: Hope that helps someone, it was usefull for me that time